# Does anyone know why work spaces move randomly?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I made the fatal mistake of upgrading my system to Ubuntu 11.04. This thing is so broken it took me weeks to get it to even boot. My problem now is that after a while (anywhere from 5-72 hours) the screen goes insane, and windows start randomly moving around to different workspaces.

This is a HUGE problem for me as I have 6 workspaces and 3 monitors. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can prevent it from happening.

---

System Specs (call to `lspci`)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RX780/RX790 Chipset Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port F)
00:11.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Device 43a0
00:16.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB368 IDE controller
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Cayman PRO [AMD Radeon 6900 Series]
05:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Device aa80
```

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Unity, AFAIK, is only meant to work with 4 workspaces by default, organized in a 2x2 grid. That might have something to do with this.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 could you please provide a link, because I can't find any articles supporting your claim.

Comment: @WarriorIng64: I have 8 workspaces with 4 along and 2 down and it works fine for me. I do only have one monitor though. (You can change this through compizconfig-settings-manager - click on the Unity application).

Comment: @puk I stand corrected. Can you provide more details on your hardware?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro I can request to have it deleted, but I don't know what else to add. Every once in a while the screen goes 'crazy', and windows get rearranged in no particular order.

Comment: Perhaps this question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).